# Dancer2 (Perl): launching an external Program in the background

Tags: javascript, perl, web-applications, dancer

I made a web application using Dancer2. I need to call an external program on an ajax request. The problem is that the request freezes until the program is finished.I tried a few things like using an & in the systemcall and fork, but it didn't work.

Here is the simplified code:

Perl:

```
package Test::App;
use Dancer2;

our $VERSION = '0.1';

get '/' => sub {
    template 'index';
};
get '/startscript' => sub{
    my $pid = fork();
    $SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';
    if($pid == 0) {
        `sleep 10`;
        exit 0;
    }
};
get '/gettest' => sub{
    return "test"
};
true;
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.get('/startscript', getSomething);
});

function getSomething(data){
    jQuery.get('/gettest', getSomething);
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: What part freezes? The browser in the frontend, or something in the backend? For the backend, how are you running your application? With a single process (i.e. perl app.pl) or with a PSGI server that has multiple processes? Have you looked into AnyEvent with Dancer2? Somewhere in the end of [this talk](http://perltv.org/v/dancer-status-2014) SawyerX is talking about using asyncronous AnyEvent with D2. I couldn't find anything more recent, but there is stuff about it out there somewhere.

Comment: I think its the backend, because the browser waits exactly 10 seconds for the response. My application runs on apache with PSGI, but i also tried to launch it with plackup. I will have a look at AnyEvent.

Comment: I am not sure what happens if you fork out of a D2 process, but it doesn't feel right. You can deploy your app with a PSGI server that supports multiple processes and then do your system call. That will make it only block one of the processes. But I think the best approach would be to look into the AnyEvent stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but the following has worked well for me - use `&` to have the shell run the command in the background. This returns control to the route handler immediately, and the command runs away in the background.

Perl:

```
post '/run-slow-script-in-background' => sub {
    my $slow_command = q{/full/path/to/slow/script --arg1 what --arg2 ever &};
    system($slow_command);
};
```